# ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 51 MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Getting this error while restarting MongoDB , I am using Mongo 3.2.4 and  doing this set up on a new machine

```
Starting mongod... about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 19438
ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 51
 mongod(_ZN5mongo19MmapV1ExtentManager4initEPNS_16OperationContextE+0x4A8) [0x1040278]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo26MMAPV1DatabaseCatalogEntryC1EPNS_16OperationContextENS_10StringDataES3_bb+0x187) [0x1036dc7]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo12MMAPV1Engine23getDatabaseCatalogEntryEPNS_16OperationContextENS_10StringDataE+0x14E) [0x103a1de]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo14DatabaseHolder6openDbEPNS_16OperationContextENS_10StringDataEPb+0x133) [0xac92a3]

-----  END BACKTRACE  -----
```

Comment: @MultiplyByZer0 my bad, up voted

Answer (score 3):

For me this error occured due to incorrect ownership of some files in my data directory. I fixed this using the following command:

```
sudo chown -R mongodb: /path/to/db/directory
```

Where mongodb was the database user in my case.

Comment: This did a trick for me. I had root:root in a lot of places. I also needed to update the sock file $ sudo chown mongod:mongod /tmp/mongodb.sock

Answer (score 1):

This is resolved by inserting the following lines into `/etc/security/limits.conf`:

```
mongodb      soft    nofile          65535
mongodb      hard    nofile          90000
mongodb      soft    nproc           65535
mongodb      hard    nproc           90000
```

We need to add the user account used to run the Mongo service. Generally, it is the `mongodb` user.

Comment: did not work for me. i added these lines and then did sudo mongod --fork --port 27017 --replSet admin --logpath /data/log/mongo.log but still get error number 51

Comment: I think the user name is `mongod`, perhaps `mongodb` was used in earlier releases.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that I haven't created the appropriate folders specified in the config files.